# How to assign a list to existing column of Pandas Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I apply some functions and generate a new column values to a existing column of Pandas dataframe. However `df['col1'] = new_list` does not work to assign new list to the column. Is it the wrong way and what is the accurate way to apply such operation ?

Comment: `df` is a dictionary ? Are you receiving an error or what? Post more details please.

Comment: I guess `df` is a Pandas' `DataFrame`, as the title and text of the question suggests.

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work" could you clarify what exactly isn't working, e.g. an example and the full stacktrace. It looks like it should work.

Comment: Yes it should've worked could you post some sample data and the errors

Answer (score 20):

It should work if length of the list is equal to the number of rows in the DataFrame

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6]})
>>> df['C'] = [10,20,30]
>>> df
   A  B   C
0  1  4  10
1  2  5  20
2  3  6  30
```

If your list is shorter or longer than DataFrame, then you'll receive an error `Length of values does not match length of index`.

Comment: You're not re-assigning a column in your example, you're merely adding a new column to it.

Comment: True, yet, works also if 'C' was defined (with different values) in the first line.

Comment: is there a way to pad with `missing` or `nan` or `Nan` or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I think this question is looking for something like this.

```
new_list = [1,2,3]

    col1
0  [1,2,3]
1  [1,2,3]
2  [1,2,3]
```

And I think I found the answer here:

[how to assign an entire list to each row of a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53116286/how-to-assign-an-entire-list-to-each-row-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: You can improve your answer by adding one or more solutions from the linked page. For example: `df['col1'] = [new_list] * len(df)`

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared some more as op asked, I just didn't want to omit /cut some useful tips (still related to the adding a list as a column), hope helps someone.

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate  
# Module tabulate is optional just for pretty printing of the Data Frame / need install if not installed i.e:  pip install tabulate


# Table1 (in terminal screen): Add a list during creation of the Data Frame #

list1 = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'avocado', 'melon', 'papaya']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1,columns = ['Fruits'])

print(tabulate(df1,headers='keys',tablefmt='pretty'),'\n')     # ==> Or just print(df1)  little messy


# Table2 : Add a list as a new column to an existing Data Frame #

list2 = ['3$','4$','2.5$','10$','5$','12$']
df1['Prices'] = list2

print(tabulate(df1,headers='keys',tablefmt='pretty'),'\n')

# Table3 : Small Trick for part4 : Add only the column name with some dummy data #

df1['Amount(Kg)'] = '0'

print(tabulate(df1,headers='keys',tablefmt='pretty'),'\n')

# Table4 : Now you can assign your existing list to an existing column  #

list3 = [100,90,80,70,60,50]
df1['Amount(Kg)'] = list3

print(tabulate(df1,headers='keys',tablefmt='pretty'),'\n')
```

Will generate the following output :

```
+---+---------+
|   | Fruits  |
+---+---------+
| 0 |  apple  |
| 1 | banana  |
| 2 | orange  |
| 3 | avocado |
| 4 |  melon  |
| 5 | papaya  |
+---+---------+

+---+---------+--------+
|   | Fruits  | Prices |
+---+---------+--------+
| 0 |  apple  |   3$   |
| 1 | banana  |   4$   |
| 2 | orange  |  2.5$  |
| 3 | avocado |  10$   |
| 4 |  melon  |   5$   |
| 5 | papaya  |  12$   |
+---+---------+--------+

+---+---------+--------+------------+
|   | Fruits  | Prices | Amount(Kg) |
+---+---------+--------+------------+
| 0 |  apple  |   3$   |     0      |
| 1 | banana  |   4$   |     0      |
| 2 | orange  |  2.5$  |     0      |
| 3 | avocado |  10$   |     0      |
| 4 |  melon  |   5$   |     0      |
| 5 | papaya  |  12$   |     0      |
+---+---------+--------+------------+

+---+---------+--------+------------+
|   | Fruits  | Prices | Amount(Kg) |
+---+---------+--------+------------+
| 0 |  apple  |   3$   |    100     |
| 1 | banana  |   4$   |     90     |
| 2 | orange  |  2.5$  |     80     |
| 3 | avocado |  10$   |     70     |
| 4 |  melon  |   5$   |     60     |
| 5 | papaya  |  12$   |     50     |
+---+---------+--------+------------+
```

If the op had added a line like in Section 3 above, his code would also work.
But As I said I wanted you to see and visualize other steps too.

```
df['col1'] = '0'
df['col1'] = new_list
```