# how to assign an entire list to each row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe and a list

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6]})
mylist= [10,20,30,40,50]
```

I would like to have a list as element in each row of a dataframe. If I do like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779015/how-to-assign-a-list-to-existing-column-of-pandas-data-frame),

```
df['C'] = mylist
```

Pandas is trying to broadcast one value per row, so I get an error `Length of values does not match length of index`.

```
   A  B   C
0  1  4  [10,20,40,50]
1  2  5  [10,20,40,50]
2  3  6  [10,20,40,50]
```

Comment: Why ever would you want to do this? .. Seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @jpp a basic usecase that comes to mind is exploding right after.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First I think working with `list`s in pandas is not [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563718/2901002).

But it is possible by list comprehension:

```
df['C'] = [mylist for i in df.index]
#another solution
#df['C'] = pd.Series([mylist] * len(df))

print (df)

   A  B                     C
0  1  4  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
1  2  5  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
2  3  6  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

Comment: why not recommended

Comment: @00__00__00 - give me a sec

Comment: pandas likes working with homogeneous data per column, each column contains specific data type. this helps accelerate any calculation done in pandas. while python list can contain any type of data. this is my understanding, probably I am wrong! @00__00__00

Answer (score 10):

One alternative using [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
df['C'] = np.tile(mylist, (len(df),1)).tolist()

print (df)

   A  B                     C
0  1  4  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
1  2  5  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
2  3  6  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

​

Answer (score 8):

Here is another solution. It makes use of `lambda` and do things "Pythonically". I think it is easier to read.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6]})
mylist= [10,20,30,40,50]
df['combined'] = df.apply(lambda x: mylist, axis=1)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just to complete my earlier answer with df.assign, borrowed list comprehension from @jezrael

```
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

>>> df.assign(C =  [mylist for i in df.index])
   A  B                     C
0  1  4  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
1  2  5  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
2  3  6  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

OR, to add permanently to the DataFrame

```
df = df.assign(C =  [mylist for i in df.index])
```

**Another way of doing it with**  `df.insert`

as we are specifying the order of the column, hence can use insert
here by inserting at index 2 (so should be third col in dataframe)

```
>>> df.insert(2, 'C', '[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]') # directly assigning the list
>>> df
   A  B                     C
0  1  4  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
1  2  5  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
2  3  6  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

Comment: If I do this on top of an .iloc selection             ''df.loc[col==val,:].assign(C=mylist)'',  this fails as ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: This will still generate the same ValueError

Answer (score 3):

That should work:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6]})
my_list = [10, 20, 30, 40]
df['C'] = [my_list] * df.shape[0]
df

A   B   C
0   1   4   [10, 20, 30, 40]
1   2   5   [10, 20, 30, 40]
2   3   6   [10, 20, 30, 40]
```

Comment: most elegant solution, in my opinion. really grabs the problem at its root: `my_list` simply needs to be repeated n-times, where `n` is shape[0] - always without any exception. - Love it!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jezrael, that working with lists in pandas is not good idea. And there is a much faster vectorized way:

1. squeeze the list into single numpy cell.
2. tile that cell and assign it to the DF.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(1e6))
mylist= [10,20,30,40,50]

#ORIGINAL:
%%timeit -n 100 
df['C'] = [mylist for i in df.index]
>>> 188 ms ± 922 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# VECTORIZED:
%%timeit -n 100 
q = np.array([1,], dtype=object)   # dummy array, note the dtype
q[0] = mylist                      # squeeze the list into single cell
df['C'] = np.tile(q, df.shape[0])  # tile and assign
>>> 12.1 ms ± 44.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The gain is especially high with larger DF sizes. (15x in this example)
Hopefully there is a more elegant way to fit a list into single numpy cell.